# Removing an object within an array with filter removes whole array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this...

```
const students = [
    {id:1, name:'ben james', major: 'BIO'},
    {id:2, name:'natasha sampson', major: 'ZOO'},
    {id:3, name:'keith franklyn', major: 'CHM'},
    ...
]
```

And I have my removeStudents() button onClick function that will take the students id and remove it from the array of students:

```
const id = event.target.id;
const students = this.state.students;
const newArr = students.filter(student => {
  student.id != event.target.id;
});
console.log(newArr); // will return []
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. It wipes the entire array clean. How can I just remove that student object within the array based on it's id?

Answer (score 2):

Your arrow function passed to the `filter()` method doesn't return anything. Either add a `return` keyword:

```
const newArr = students.filter(student => {
  return student.id != event.target.id;
});
```

or get rid of the curly braces:

```
const newArr = students.filter(student => student.id != event.target.id);
```